# Use Angular Library Locally In New/Separate Application

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8, angular-library

I am trying to include a library I built in a new application. It builds successfully but I get an error on runtime `main.ts:13 Error: inject() must be called from an injection context`.

When I grab the library from npm using `npm i devicewise-angular` there is no problem. Everything runs fine.

The test application that is generated with the library also can use the local library just fine.

I've added the paths to my `tsconfig.json` file.

```
{
  ...
  "compilerOptions": {
  ...
    "paths": {
      "devicewise-angular": [
        "../devicewise-angular/dist/devicewise-angular"
      ]
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

The library is most definitely found and it builds fine. VSCode intellisense is auto completing everything.

Here is the error

```
main.ts:13 Error: inject() must be called from an injection context
    at injectInjectorOnly (core.js:520)
    at ɵɵinject (core.js:536)
    at DevicewiseAngularService_Factory (devicewise-angular.js:984)
    at _callFactory (core.js:23211)
    at _createProviderInstance (core.js:23154)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:23113)
    at NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:24206)
    at resolveDep (core.js:24736)
    at createClass (core.js:24584)
    at createDirectiveInstance (core.js:24400)
```

Looking at `devicewise-angular.js:984` I see:

```
/** @nocollapse */ DevicewiseAngularService.ngInjectableDef = ɵɵdefineInjectable({ factory: function DevicewiseAngularService_Factory() { return new DevicewiseAngularService(ɵɵinject(CookieService), ɵɵinject(DevicewiseApiService), ɵɵinject(DevicewiseSubscribeService), ɵɵinject(DevicewiseMultisubscribeService)); }, token: DevicewiseAngularService, providedIn: "root" });
```

I expect the same result using a local version of the library as if I installed it using npm. Why do I get this static injection error when trying to use it like this?

Answer (score 0):

Careful with this kind of hacks, as this is not the way node-dependencies work.

A library can be "emulated" locally, by `linking` it with your dependency manager (npm or yarn).
Run `npm link` inside the folder with your local library with its `package.json` (.../dist/devicewise-angular), and you will be able to run `npm link devicewise-angular` in your angular project, and it will use your local copy instead the official one.

Please refer to the [official documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link) to study its details.
Happy coding!